# install .ova on physical machine

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

[Hortonworks Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#install) is available only as .ova file.
I need to install it on physical machine without esx, or VirtualBox, just raw machine. 
Is that possible? If so, how to install it?

Comment: What makes you think it has all the drivers for all of your peripherals????

Answer (score -1):

Even as it might be very much possible to extract the OVA it is nowhere near recommended to be done. The virtual appliance may only contain generic drivers and might not run at all. You can also forget about getting any support, so really not recommended.

Just bite the bullet and use the appliance as it was intended.

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer to the author's question.

Comment: Well, as someone who has some experience in virtual appliances, there will be more issues than benefit. The virtual appliance may only contain generic drivers and might not run at all. You can also forget about getting any support, so really not recommended.